# How to allow only numbers on the phone's keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I want to use only numbers in the input field. How to allow only numbers (iOS and Android) on the phone keypad like on this screen https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0eU9chNlIdabU1VTWQycy1mb3M?usp=sharing

Inputmode = "numeric" does not work :(

```js
$('.input-number').on('input', function (event) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input-number" type="text" maxlength="5" inputmode="numeric">
```

Comment: type="number" does the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `type="number"` attribute on `Input` element.

Answer (score 0):

Add a pattern to your input similar to one mentioned below
pattern='[0-9]*'

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Type=tel` like this:

```
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{10}" name="tel" title="Phone Number?!?!"/>
```